# If the square of a real number lies between 1500 and 1600, then what can we conclude?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If the square of a real number lies between 1500 and 1600, then the real number lies between:
>
> - a. 25, 30
> - b. 30, 35
> - c. 35, 40
> - d. 40, 45
> - e. 45, 50

My answer is that the real number lies between **10√15** and **40**.
Is the correct answer of the question be one of these choices?

Comment: Your calculation is precise. There are no options that match your claim bar one; it should be easy to spot without an estimation of $\sqrt{15}$. But, we can say $3.5<\sqrt{15}$ if that helps

Comment: Hint: if a number lies between 4.234237 and 7.3783742, it also lies between 5 and 7

Comment: Thanks  , you helped me alot !

Comment: We can do this by squaring the numbers given in a...e and comparing to 1500 and 1600.  This can be done by hand, with no calculator, right?

Comment: @barrycarter unfortunately your example is false

Comment: @s.harp It was but I edited it. Sorry.

Comment: Since $(-39)^2=1521$ the answer is “none of the above”.

Comment: @barrycarter Still seem to be going the other way. I think you meant to say : if a number lies between $5$ and $7$, then it lies between $4.234237$ and $7.37842$. To the reverse statement (which is your comment), $4.5$ would be a counterexample.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer You're right. I'll leave the comment up as a tribute to my lack of intelligence, but, of course, I meant the opposite.

Comment: Since this is a multiple-choice question, as a matter of test-taking strategy you can first look at all the choices. You know that $\sqrt{1599}$ (among other numbers that should be included in the answer) is between $39$ and $40.$ Only one of the answers allows a number that is between $39$ and $40,$ and that is choice (c). Since "none of the above" was not offered as a choice, you can conclude that the person(s) making the test forgot about the negative square roots. So answer (c) is wrong but is most likely the "correct" answer according to the answer key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$1500\le x^2\le1600
\\\iff\sqrt{1500}\le |x|\le\sqrt{1600}
\\\iff (x\le-38.7\;\text{ or }\;x\ge38.7) \;\text{ and }\;-40\le x\le40
\\\iff -40\le x\le-38.7\;\text{ or }\;38.7\le x\le40.$$
Thus, $$1500\le x^2\le1600\;\text{ and }\;x\ge0\\
\implies38.7\le x\le40\\
\implies35<x<40.$$

Therefore, if the question is reworded to "If the square of a ***nonnegative*** real number...", then the answer is Option C.